# What is the best way for on demand download and install of dlls in .NET?

Tags: c#

We have an application that we wish to install just a basic shell for. As the users use it, it will download and install the necessary dlls for actions that need to take place (imagine a wizard application scenario with several possible paths). Currently, everything is installed for all possible paths through the shell app.

For about 3 months out of the year, the dlls used for the possible paths go through a high churn rate with updates, so we wish to start ensuring the users have the most recent version of these dlls. The idea is that after all their selections are made, we'd make a web check to see what dlls are required for their selection and check to make sure they have the most recent version of those files.

All of this we have a plan for on how to do it. The problem I'm fighting is what is the most appropriate way to "install" these files. ClickOnce is not an option...too much legacy stuff here. Our app is installed in "Program Files" which obviously has restrictions for writing random files into the program's install folder under Vista and later.

Right now I see the options as the following:

1. On install mark the install directory as writable for the "Everyone" group. I haven't actually tested to see if this would work yet, or if Vista does something different in this scenario.
2. Split the download portion out into a second app that we can have prompt for elevated privileges so that it can download and install these files.

I'm leaning towards the second option since that maintains the security aspect of the Program Files folder. Others in the group lean towards the first option because they just don't want to have to worry about things. Or is there some other option I'm missing?

The app is a .NET app, though it has some requirements of third party dlls that are not managed assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the dlls you want to load are managed, there are several ways to do this.

One way is to designate an Environment.SpecialFolder path such as AppData and dynamically load assemblies into your appdomain from there. [RssBandit](http://rssbandit.org/) does this for plugins, there is a special directory that loads dlls and searches for specific interface implementations, loads them into a temporary appdomain, and then calls them from the app. You could take this one step further by using an IoC library like [ninject](http://ninject.org/) or [structuremap](http://structuremap.sourceforge.net/Default.htm).

you could also try [MEF](http://www.codeplex.com/MEF), the new extensibility framework coming out in C# 4.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I like what Firefox/xul apps do.  It's a hybrid of your two proposed solutions, I suppose.  They have an updater.exe that lives in the install directory.  I assume that means that the install directory is made writable during install so that they can run the update application.  However, having never deployed a application in this manner, I can't tell you how much of a headache (or not) it is.

An alternative which you haven't mentioned, and may not know about, is using the .Net download cache.  When you attempt to load an assembly you can give it a code base to load from.  If you set the codebase to a web url (i.e. http://mywebhost/mycoolapp/) .Net will download the assembly from that url if it's not found in the download cache.  It will also grab the latest version of the assembly from the web url if there is one.

This approach can be a pain as you'll likely have to deal with CAS security issues if your app needs elevated permissions.  However, it is nice not having to write code to download the latest versions of your assemblies for you.  If you want more information, I can find some resources and give more detailed examples.

Answer (score 0):

The way I handle it is to have an update.exe installed into program files next to the main .exe file.

Then, on app startup, I have the app download an xml file off of the web and save it in the App Data folder.  This file contains the latest versions of the dlls and has a simple Filename, Version structure.

Run through the list of filenames and if you don't have the dll locally or you have an older version, then add the needed dll to an update list.

After you generate your update list.  Fire off the Updater.exe with a command line list of the files to be updated.  You don't have to write them to program files but I do.  On Vista, my updater pops up the UAC prompt correctly (as it should to maintain Program Files' security).

The updater then downloads the files to Program Files and restarts the main app.

One problem with firing off the second app is that you have to give it a manifest with "AsAdministrator" set in it.

This isn't hard to do, but once the updater is done and retriggers the main app, it cannot start the main app with normal privileges.  An exe running as administrator can only start other exe's as administrator also, even if "AsInvoker" is set in the manifest.  I don't know why you can't restrict it back to normal rights...you can only elevate permissions for some reason...